# tensorflow TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was doing cs231n assignment 2 and encountered this problem.

I'm using tensorflow-gpu 1.5.0

Code as following

```
# define our input (e.g. the data that changes every batch)
# The first dim is None, and gets sets automatically based on batch size fed in
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 32, 32, 3])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None])
is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

# define model
def complex_model(X,y,is_training):
    pass

y_out = complex_model(X,y,is_training)

# Now we're going to feed a random batch into the model 
# and make sure the output is the right size
x = np.random.randn(64, 32, 32,3)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.device("/cpu:0"): #"/cpu:0" or "/gpu:0"
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    ans = sess.run(y_out,feed_dict={X:x,is_training:True})
    %timeit sess.run(y_out,feed_dict={X:x,is_training:True})
    print(ans.shape)
    print(np.array_equal(ans.shape, np.array([64, 10])))
```

Complete traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-97f0b6c5a72e> in <module>()
      6         tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
      7 
----> 8         ans = sess.run(y_out,feed_dict={X:x,is_training:True})
      9         get_ipython().run_line_magic('timeit',     'sess.run(y_out,feed_dict={X:x,is_training:True})')
     10         print(ans.shape)

c:\users\kasper\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-    packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    893     try:
    894       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 895                          run_metadata_ptr)
    896       if run_metadata:
    897         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

c:\users\kasper\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1111     # Create a fetch handler to take care of the structure of fetches.
   1112     fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(
-> 1113         self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor,     feed_handles=feed_handles)
   1114 
   1115     # Run request and get response.

c:\users\kasper\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, graph, fetches, feeds, feed_handles)
    419     with graph.as_default():
--> 420       self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
    421     self._fetches = []
    422     self._targets = []

c:\users\kasper\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
    235     if fetch is None:
    236       raise TypeError('Fetch argument %r has invalid type %r' %
--> 237                       (fetch, type(fetch)))
    238     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
    239       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.

TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

I saw that similar questions have been asked on this site before,but those don't seem to solve mine.

Any help would be appreciated,thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `y_out` argument to `sess.run()` is `None`, whereas it must be a `tf.Tensor` (or tensor-like object, such as a `tf.Variable`) or a `tf.Operation`.

In your example, `y_out` is defined by the following code:

```
# define model
def complex_model(X,y,is_training):
    pass

y_out = complex_model(X,y,is_training)
```

`complex_model()` doesn't return a value, so `y_out = complex_model(...)` will set `y_out` to `None`. I'm not sure if this function is representative of your real code, but it's possible that your real `complex_model()` function is also missing a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that **mrry** is right.

If you give a second look the the notebook [Assignment 2 - Tensorflow.ipynb](https://github.com/BedirYilmaz/cs231-stanford/blob/master/assignment2/TensorFlow.ipynb), you will notice the description cell as follows :

> Training a specific model
>
> In this section, we're going to specify a model for you to construct.
>   The goal here isn't to get good performance (that'll be next), but
>   instead to get comfortable with understanding the TensorFlow
>   documentation and configuring your own model.
>
> Using the code provided above as guidance, and using the following
>   TensorFlow documentation, specify a model with the following
>   architecture:
>
> ```
> 7x7 Convolutional Layer with 32 filters and stride of 1
> ReLU Activation Layer
> Spatial Batch Normalization Layer (trainable parameters, with scale and centering)
> 2x2 Max Pooling layer with a stride of 2
> Affine layer with 1024 output units
> ReLU Activation Layer
> Affine layer from 1024 input units to 10 outputs
> ```

Which is **asking you to define a model** inside the function

```
# define model
def complex_model(X,y,is_training):
    pass
```

Just like they did in

```
def simple_model(X,y):
    # define our weights (e.g. init_two_layer_convnet)

    # setup variables
    Wconv1 = tf.get_variable("Wconv1", shape=[7, 7, 3, 32])
    bconv1 = tf.get_variable("bconv1", shape=[32])
    W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", shape=[5408, 10])
    b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", shape=[10])

    # define our graph (e.g. two_layer_convnet)
    a1 = tf.nn.conv2d(X, Wconv1, strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='VALID') + bconv1
    h1 = tf.nn.relu(a1)
    h1_flat = tf.reshape(h1,[-1,5408])
    y_out = tf.matmul(h1_flat,W1) + b1
    return y_out
```

Hope this helps!