# Multiple Networks yielding Tensorflow TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I am working with OpenAI gym to train an actor-critic network where one network provides the action and the second network provides the expected value. However, I keep getting the `TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>` error when I attempt to get the gradients from the network to be stored so I can update them later. It only appears when I run it with the critic network or if I run a second actor network. I have defined them with different `tf.variable_scope` values and passed the same session, so it seems to me that it ought to work and I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't. I came across other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432618/tensorflow-error-typeerror-fetch-argument-none-has-invalid-type-type-nonetyp), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114832/tensorflow-typeerror-fetch-argument-none-has-invalid-type-type-nonetype), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788169/tensorflow-typeerror-fetch-argument-none-has-invalid-type-class-nonetype), yet they don't address my issue.

My network is given as (for brevity I cut out the layers and other methods that are working, also the actor network is nearly identical at this level of abstraction, just a different loss function; I can provide more code if deemed necessary):

```
# Define critic network
class critic(object):    
    def __init__(self, sess, scope):

        self.sess = sess
        self.scope = scope
        with tf.variable_scope(self.scope):
          # Network inputs, outputs, rewards, optimizer, etc...
          self.state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.n_inputs],
                                    name='state')
          self.returns = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], name='returns')
          # Single, linear layer
          self.output = fully_connected(self.state, self.n_out, 
                                      activation_fn=None,
                                      weights_initializer=None)

          self.est_state_value = tf.squeeze(self.output)
          # Define loss function
          self.loss = tf.squared_difference(self.est_state_value, self.returns)
          self.trainable_variables = tf.trainable_variables()
          self.gradients = tf.gradients(self.loss, self.trainable_variables)

    # Methods for prediction, updating, etc...
```

And the `get_grads` method which is intended to return the network gradients is causing the problems:

```
def get_grads(self, states, actions, returns):
    grads = self.sess.run([self.gradients], 
        feed_dict={
        self.state: states,
        self.actions: actions,
        self.returns: returns
        })[0]
    return grads
```

When running the algorithm, it throws the error on the second `get_grads` call.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

sess = tf.Session()
act = actor(sess, scope='actor')
crit = critic(sess, scope='critic')
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
act.sess.run(init)
crit.sess.run(init)
# Randomized data for example
rewards = np.ones(10)
actions = np.random.choice([0, 1], 10)
states = np.random.normal(size=(10, 4))

act.get_grads(states, actions, rewards)
crit.get_grads(states, rewards)
```

It made me think that perhaps it was due to similar naming conventions between the two networks, so I tried making changes there, using two separate `tf.Session()` values, and other things, but the problem persists. If I just run a single network - the actor or critic - everything executes fine and it learns properly. So, I'm not sure what's going on here causing this error or how to fix it. I'd be grateful for any help here.

Full traceback:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-78-c56d39a21e63> in <module>()
         13 
         14 act.get_grads(states, actions, rewards)
    ---> 15 crit.get_grads(states, rewards)

    <ipython-input-76-031f8b9688f5> in get_grads(self, states, returns)
         53             feed_dict={
         54             self.state: states,
    ---> 55             self.returns: returns
         56             })
         57         return grads

    ...\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
        903     try:
        904       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
    --> 905                          run_metadata_ptr)
        906       if run_metadata:
        907         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

    ...\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
       1120     # Create a fetch handler to take care of the structure of fetches.
       1121     fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(
    -> 1122         self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
       1123 
       1124     # Run request and get response.

    ...\client\session.py in __init__(self, graph, fetches, feeds, feed_handles)
        425     """
        426     with graph.as_default():
    --> 427       self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
        428     self._fetches = []
        429     self._targets = []

    ...\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
        243     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
        244       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.
    --> 245       return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
        246     elif isinstance(fetch, dict):
        247       return _DictFetchMapper(fetch)

    ...\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, fetches)
        350     """
        351     self._fetch_type = type(fetches)
    --> 352     self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
        353     self._unique_fetches, self._value_indices = _uniquify_fetches(self._mappers)
        354 

   ...\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in <listcomp>(.0)
        350     """
        351     self._fetch_type = type(fetches)
    --> 352     self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
        353     self._unique_fetches, self._value_indices = _uniquify_fetches(self._mappers)
        354 

   ...\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
        243     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
        244       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.
    --> 245       return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
        246     elif isinstance(fetch, dict):
        247       return _DictFetchMapper(fetch)

    ...\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, fetches)
        350     """
        351     self._fetch_type = type(fetches)
    --> 352     self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
        353     self._unique_fetches, self._value_indices = _uniquify_fetches(self._mappers)
        354 

   ...\client\session.py in <listcomp>(.0)
        350     """
        351     self._fetch_type = type(fetches)
    --> 352     self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
        353     self._unique_fetches, self._value_indices = _uniquify_fetches(self._mappers)
        354 

    ...\client\session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
        240     if fetch is None:
        241       raise TypeError('Fetch argument %r has invalid type %r' % (fetch,
    --> 242                                                                  type(fetch)))
        243     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
        244       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.

    TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: Just a sanity check, after the line `act.get_grads(...)`, these variables don't get set to `None`? `crit.gradients`, `states`, and `rewards`

Comment: Yes, it has values when I run it the first, time, then it becomes `None` on the second iteration. But, this only occurs when there are multiple networks, if I'm just running with the actor or critic alone, it never encounters this issue.

Comment: which variable becomes `None`?

Answer (score 0):

Although I had been calling `self.trainable_variables = tf.trainable_variables()` within a unique, `tf.variable_scope(self.scope)`, the way I was sequentially initializing the networks led the first network to initialize properly, then the second network had all the trainable variables assigned to `self.trainable_variables` after initialization. To fix it, I simply needed to be explicit when defining the variables for each network by changing the call to:

```
self.trainable_variables = tf.trainable_variables(self.scope)
```